# Are the broken platforms ever useful in Doodle Jump?

Tags: doodle-jump

I recently bought Doodle Jump for Android, and keep dying because I accidentally land on the broken platforms.

Do these ever serve a useful purpose, e.g. to slow you down if you're travelling at high speed?  Or are they there merely to distract from the viable platforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I studied some video of someone playing the game, and I don't think they have any effect on the physics of your character.  Touching them doesn't appear to slow you down or give you any additional opportunity to change direction.  I think they're just there to give you a false sense of hope :)

Comment: You are correct. They're only there to confuse you so sometimes when you have to make a split second decision, you go for the broken platform by accident.

Answer (score 3):

They are only useful to get two achievements:

- **Epic Fail**: Break 50 platforms in one game.
- **Epic Fail FTW**: Broke 1000 platforms total.

If your version of Doodle Jump doesn't have achievements, they're useless.